# How to install Firefox OS SDK on MacOS?

Tags: firefox-os

I'd like to start developing for Firefox OS, but I'm having problem to install.. I' m following the mozilla's wikis, but now I don't know how to continue.
I've downloaded XULRunner, but then what should I do? I'm trying to follow the wiki, but without finding a solution.

Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Getting_started_with_XULRunner

Comment: Can you add a link to the wiki?

Comment: Now I'm stopped at step 3.. I lost much time with the wrong file to install

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no SDK for Firefox OS. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Apps on Firefox OS are web apps, so you can use whatever tools you already use for web development to develop apps. If you'd like to test out your app in the context of the mobile UI provided by Firefox OS you can use the Firefox OS Simulator which is a Firefox plugin https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firefox-os-simulator/

If you'd like to contribute to Gaia (the collection of web apps which make up the user interface) take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS/Platform/Gaia/Hacking

If you'd like to build the whole OS and/or contribute to the Gonk (kernel) and Gecko (web app runtime) parts then have a look at the README on GitHub https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/B2G/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 2):

Maybe It can be usefully

This is a nice slide
http://shafiul.github.io/slides/kickstart_fxos.html#/

And the Alfa simulator
http://people.mozilla.org/~myk/r2d2b2g/
It works well for me

Answer (score 2):

All you need is the most recent version of Firefox and the [Firefox OS simulator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Firefox_OS_Simulator) (consider installing Firefox Nightly)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Quickstart/Build/Your_first_app

Comment: why should I install nightly?

Comment: It is recommended in the docs: "We'd recommend using a prerelease version for testing, such as Aurora or Nightly." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Marketplace/Submission/Testing_and_troubleshooting