# Get started with mozilaa os development

Tags: mozilla

I wan to develop apps for the lastest mozilla mobile os, but I dont where to download SDK and other tools.

I searched a lot but I couldn't find any useful information.

Looking forward to your answers....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Firefox OS SDK on MacOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456093/how-to-install-firefox-os-sdk-on-macos)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can follow following links...

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/os/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Quickstart

And you can downlaod the SDK at---
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Gecko_SDK....

I hope it would help you......

Comment: Can you show me some tutorials on this or any sample code...?